# running a Docker container with Java application and a webserver doesnt work

Tags: java, node.js, docker

Im a new to docker and i am trying to create a container running multiple services,
using this documentation:[Run multiple services in a container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/multi-service_container/)

I've managed to get Java and Nodejs installed on the containe, eventually leading to running this script at the end of the Dockerfile as an ENTRYPOINT:

```html
#!/bin/bash
# Start the first process
/tmp/cliffer/bin/startup.sh &
status=$?
if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Failed to start my_first_process: $status"
  exit $status
fi

# Start the second process
npm start &
status=$?
if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Failed to start my_second_process: $status"
  exit $status
fi

# Naive check runs checks once a minute to see if either of the processes exited.
# This illustrates part of the heavy lifting you need to do if you want to run
# more than one service in a container. The container will exit with an error
# if it detects that either of the processes has exited.
# Otherwise it will loop forever, waking up every 60 seconds
  
while /bin/true; do
  PROCESS_1_STATUS=$(ps aux |grep -q my_first_process |grep -v grep)
  PROCESS_2_STATUS=$(ps aux |grep -q my_second_process | grep -v grep)
  # If the greps above find anything, they will exit with 0 status
  # If they are not both 0, then something is wrong
  if [ $PROCESS_1_STATUS -ne 0 -o $PROCESS_2_STATUS -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "One of the processes has already exited."
    exit -1
  fi
  sleep 60
done
```

both services are running in the background, and the result is that the npm start, starts a webserver but immediately shuts it down.
This is the output im getting from the `npm start &`

```
[--:--:--][CONSOLE] [09:19:11] [Start] Listening at port 3000
[09:19:11] [Stop] Shutting down
```

when I run the the container with each of the services separately in a container of its own it works perfect.

any ideas why?

Comment: Not answering your question, but it worth mentioning that in general it's recommended to run 1 service per container, and if you want several service you could use docker-compose. That being said, when you say they work fine separately, is it with the same ENTRYPOINT point to a bash script? Or directly pointing to "npm start"?

Answer (score 0):

Docker needs one process to run in the foreground otherwise it will exit. Your foreground program is your entrypoint that sleeps for 60 seconds and checks if both processes are still in the background.

The check is for the process name "my_first_process". That should be for your instance be something like "java"

so instead of

```
ps aux |grep -q my_first_process |grep -v grep
ps aux |grep -q my_second_process |grep -v grep
```

try

```
ps aux |grep -q java |grep -v grep
ps aux |grep -q npm |grep -v grep
```

Joel's comment is still valid, it makes more sense to run two different docker containers for your use case.

Comment: The first service monitors the packets coming into the webserver thats why running it in 2 probably wont work..

Comment: you can monitor the internal docker network, link docker containers or use a common volume, but if your two processes clearly belong together, you have justified placing them in one container.